# Why is Kafka Producer ack=all so slow when sending synchronous messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a `Kafka version : 0.9.0.1` application that is sending messages synchronously with `ack=all`.

With this setting I achieve a message per second of approx. 75.

When I change to `ack=1` I increase my throughput to 453 messages per second.

Why does `ack=all` run 6 times slower?

My target Kafka topics have a single partition and replication set to 3.

Is there any way I can increase the performance of `ack=all`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way I can increase the performance of ack=all?

Use async send with message retry enabled. messages will be sent in batch, you will get better throughput.

async send does not mean losing data, message retry and message send callback could be leveraged to guarantee the send success even when  `(replication factor - min.insync.replicas)` brokers down.

Comment: I cannot have messages re trying, as this can result in messages out of sequence. I have to use synchronous sending

Answer (score 3):

There is no way because ack setting is designed for trade-off between performance and the change of losing data.
So, you cannot choose both.

Comment: I get that, but why does getting ack from three servers 6 times slower than from 1?

Comment: When you send message: Client --> Leader -->Replica.   Then leader wait for all replica ack to leader, then leader sent ack to client: Replica --> Leader --> Client. I think with replica =3, it should be slow from 2-4 times, but in general the network time is unpredicable.

Comment: I would expect ack=all to be slower than ack=1, however we are seeing 6 - 8 times slower (actually closer to 8 times slower). Where I would expect 3 - 4 times slower at most. How can I discover how Kafka implements ack=all?